# Notification after directory delete is done

Tags: c#, directory

When I use Directory.Delete, the delete completes after I update my controls tied to the folder structure.

```
 Directory.Delete(System.IO.Path.Combine(StorageSchemaPath, selectedSKU), true);
```

I have considering starting a timer to check when delete completes or timeout.

Are there any event notifications I can tie into instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach a System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to the directory above and use the OnDeleted event.

See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.ondeleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly what I was looking for.